# Proper use of mysql sum function

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
 Field            | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SMILES          | char(200)            | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| ConfRank        | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CompTime        | double               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I want to get the total CompTime for a specific SMILES (meaning Comptime are added for al confrank of a specific smiles).

I tried the following:

```
SELECT SMILES,(SUM(CompTime)) From GeoAndEnergies  GROUP BY  ConfRank  WHERE  SMILES='C';
```

And received this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '`WHERE  SMILES='C'`' at line 1

I also tried:

```
SELECT SMILES,(SUM(CompTime)) From GeoAndEnergies  GROUP BY  ConfRank  WHERE  SMILES='C' GROUPBY ConfRank ;
```

And received another error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '`WHERE  SMILES='C' GROUPBY ConfRank`' at line 1

What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
 SELECT SMILES,(SUM(CompTime)) From GeoAndEnergies WHERE  SMILES='C' GROUP BY  ConfRank;
```

Comment: where is your method field in your table

Answer (score 0):

Your `group by` clause should appear after `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

so I used 
SELECT SMILES, (SUM(CompTime)) From GeoAndEnergies WHERE  Method ='PM6' GROUP BY SMILES  INTO OUTFILE "/var/lib/mysql-files/data_PM6_timesum" ;
and
mysql> SELECT SMILES, (SUM(CompTime)) From GeoAndEnergies WHERE  Method ='PM6' GROUP BY SMILES  INTO OUTFILE "/var/lib/mysql-files/data_PM6_time" ;
 and  SELECT SMILES, NRotBond , NHeavyAtom  From GeoAndEnergies WHERE  Method ='PM6' AND ConfRank =1  INTO OUTFILE "/var/lib/mysql-files//data_PM6_rotheavy" ; 
to create data_PM6_rotheavy and data_PM6_time.
By catting the 2 you should have what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Your `GROUP BY` should follow the `WHERE` clause. Update as follows:

```
  SELECT `SMILES`,
         SUM(`CompTime`)  
    FROM `GeoAndEnergies`  
   WHERE `SMILES` = 'C'
GROUP BY  `ConfRank`;
```